# How to filter data and then group in one statement using pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by

Is there any possibility to filter data and then group in one statement using pandas?

I need to implement the query like that:

```
SELECT ParsedPickupMonth, COUNT(*)
FROM df
WHERE trip_distance > 0 and trip_distance < 3
GROUP BY ParsedPickupMonth
```

My idea:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("yellow_tripdata_2019-01.csv")

df['ParsedPickupMonth'][(df.trip_distance > 0) & (df.trip_distance < 3)].groupby(???).count()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
df[(df.trip_distance > 0) & (df.trip_distance < 3)].groupby('ParsedPickupMonth').count().max(axis=1).rename('count').reset_index()
```

You should end up with something like:

```
ParsedPickupMonth  count
              Jan      6
              Feb      2
              Mar      7
```

Comment: Thank you, it works well. Just need to replace "&&" by "&"